# Monotone class: verification

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> **Definition.** A non empty family $\mathcal{M}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ is called monotone class on $X$ if for every monotone sequence $\{E_n\}\subseteq \mathcal{M}$ it holds that $\lim E_n \in \mathcal{M}$.

The family $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra, and $\mathcal{M}_0(\mathcal{A})$ is the monotone class generated by $\mathcal{A}$, $F\in\mathcal{A}$.

We consider the following three families of sets:
$$\tilde{\mathcal{A}}=\{E\in\mathcal{M}_0(\mathcal{A})\;|\;\complement E\in\mathcal{M}_0(\mathcal{A})\},$$

$$\hat{\mathcal{A}_F}=\{E\in\mathcal{M}_0(\mathcal{A})\;|\;E\cup F\in\mathcal{M}_0(\mathcal{A})\},$$

$$\hat{\mathcal{A}}=\{F\in\mathcal{M}_0(\mathcal{A})\;|\; E\cup F\in\mathcal{M}_0(\mathcal{A})\quad\forall E\in\mathcal{M}_0(\mathcal{A})\}.$$

> **Question.** I must show that these three families are monotone classes. Could someone provide me a proof of this fact?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a simple application of the definition. What have you tried and where do you strand?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right. On reflection, it was not that difficult. Thank you!